# What size cone wrench am I likely to need for a Trek 1.5 2011 Compact rear hub?

Tags: hub, trek

Unfortunately the manufacturer's website, and google don't appear to hold this information. The only thing I've found is that the hubs are aluminium which doesn't really help.

Is there a common size of wrench? If I get the size wrong I can always send it back but I'm guessing people who deal with road bikes a lot will know that there's a common set of sizes.

Any suggestions? :)

Comment: 17, 15 and 13mm are common sizes. No idea about this wheel though. If you've some callipers you could measure the cone.

Comment: Just buy a set -- not much more than a single wrench, and the front will probably use a different size from the rear anyway.

Comment: Try to find one of these: it has 4 sizes (IIRC, 14, 15, 16 and 17mm) on a single wrench: http://www.totalbike.rs/pribor/alati/univerzalni-alat-za-konuse

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I had a 2008 version of the 1.5 bike and the rear wheel took a 15mm cone wrench.

It's possible that Trek changed this, but I think 15mm is a good bet.

I agree with @alex; anything other than 13, 15, or 17 would be considered uncommon.

Comment: It was indeed 15mm.

Answer (score 1):

According to the Q&A section on Wiggle I need a 15 / 16mm wrench:

http://www.wiggle.co.uk/park-tools-double-ended-cone-wrench/

Comment: This was the correct size in practice.